# Gradle and Jackson dependency

Tags: kotlin, gradle, jackson

I am new to Gradle and Kotlin and I am starting building my first app. I want to use the jackson module in order to serialize map objects.
My gradle file looks the following

```
import org.jsonschema2pojo.InclusionLevel


buildscript {
    ext.js2p_version = "1.0.0"

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.jsonschema2pojo:jsonschema2pojo-gradle-plugin:${js2p_version}")
    }

}

plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.4.10'
}

group = "me"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
repositories {
    jcenter()
}


apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "jsonschema2pojo"


jsonSchema2Pojo {
    source = files("src/main/resources/config.json")
    targetPackage = 'com.config'
    removeOldOutput = true
    classNameSuffix = 'Desc'
    inclusionLevel = InclusionLevel.ALWAYS
    includeJsr303Annotations = true
    useBigDecimals = true
    includeAdditionalProperties = true
}

dependencies {
    //implementation platform("com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.10.1")
    implementation platform("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.11.0")
    //implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.11.+"
    /**
     * This dependency does not need to be 100% in-sync with the main project.
     */
    compileOnly 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations'
    compileOnly 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind'
    compileOnly 'javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.1.Final'
    testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit'

}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
```

However when I try to build it, I get an error in my info.kt class (ocated under main directory)

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Comment: whats the question?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

`KotlinModule` is part of `com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin` which you commented out in the Gradle file.

Uncomment it and the import should start working.